# Microsoft vpn application triggering: connection OK, but browser doesn't use vpn

Tags: vpn

My code following the [theory](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2016/01/25/step-by-step-enabling-apps-to-auto-trigger-vpns-in-windows-10/):

```
Set-VpnConnection -Name fr1-ovpn-tcp.pointtoserver.com -SplitTunneling $True

Set-VpnConnection –Name fr1-ovpn-tcp.pointtoserver.com –IdleDisconnectSeconds 10

Add-VpnConnectionTriggerApplication -Name fr1-ovpn-tcp.pointtoserver.com –ApplicationID "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

Get-VpnConnection -Name fr1-ovpn-tcp.pointtoserver.com
```

Result:

```
Name                  : fr1-ovpn-tcp.pointtoserver.com
ServerAddress         : fr1-ovpn-tcp.pointtoserver.com
AllUserConnection     : False
Guid                  : {54F2D82B-1205-4998-86BB-956E0D18BC66}
TunnelType            : Automatic
AuthenticationMethod  : {Eap}
EncryptionLevel       : Optional
L2tpIPsecAuth         : Certificate
UseWinlogonCredential : False
EapConfigXmlStream    : #document
ConnectionStatus      : Disconnected
RememberCredential    : True
SplitTunneling        : True
DnsSuffix             : 
IdleDisconnectSeconds : 10


Get-VpnConnectionTrigger -ConnectionName fr1-ovpn-tcp.pointtoserver.com
```

Result:

```
ConnectionName         : fr1-ovpn-tcp.pointtoserver.com
ApplicationID          : {C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe}
```

Everything is OK, when I start the browser (any browser does the same) the connection is established automatically, when I 
https://ipcim.com/en/?p=where
try to figure out which is the location of the browser, I get my home country IP address and not - in this example - an ip address from France.

When I use VPN as usual, the ip address shows that I am in France.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem: vpn connection start but then the application who started the connection still uses ISP connection instead of VPN

Answer (score 0):

You specified -SplitTunneling - all traffic that is not specifically for the tunnel network will go via your internet connection.

Comment: AutoTriggering does not work without SplitTunneling, at least accroding to the articel referenced by the OP.

Comment: As OP wrote to enable AutoTrigger you have to enable splittunneling. In this way all traffic should be redirected to ISP except fot the application listed in the autotrigger...but it seems not working